# How to obtain an odds ratio and 95% CI between two specific clusters in a multilevel logistic model?

Tags: confidence-interval, multilevel-analysis, odds-ratio

I was wondering how one would estimate an odds ratio (OR) and its 95% confidence interval (CI) for the difference between two specific clusters/groups in a two-level multilevel logistic model? I understand that you can pull the cluster-specific residual terms and use this to obtain estimate's of cluster-specific log-odds (which can be used to calculate the OR) ... but then how would you go about obtaining the 95% CI around it?

Comment: Bayesian random effects models work better than frequentist ones, and can provide exact inference for that type of contrast.  But in the frequentist domain there is probably a BLUP contrast available.

Comment: @FrankHarrell thank you so much!

Comment: Check out merTools' `predictInterval` for a great set of options for getting the intervals @FrankHarrell is suggesting. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/Using_predictInterval.html

Comment: @ErikRuzek this is awesome, thank you!